# How to change background image of a button and get it updated instantly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, background, uibutton

Im developing a memory game. As i click on a button I want the background to switch. When I click on the card the second time i want the background to switch for a second and then go back to the original (if it wasnt the correct card). But the background of the buttons are not changed until i return from the method (buttonPressed). Why isnt it changed instantly? Please help me! :)

**Here is the class that i am working with:**

```
#import "Button.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@class ZogajAppDelegate;

@interface PairPlayPlayViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    ZogajAppDelegate *appDelegate;
    AVAudioPlayer *av;
    Boolean isPairActive;
    Button *firstButton;
    Button *secondButton;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *av;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Button *firstButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Button *secondButton;
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
- (void)secondCard;

@end
```

**and the .m file:**

```
#import "PairPlayPlayViewController.h"
#import "ZogajAppDelegate.h"
#import "Button.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"



@implementation PairPlayPlayViewController
@synthesize av, firstButton, secondButton;

/*
 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *newAudioFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"double_card" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSString *newAudioFile2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"right_sound" ofType:@"mp3"];

    av = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioFile] error:NULL];
    [av prepareToPlay];
    [av initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioFile2] error:NULL];
    [av prepareToPlay];
    //av = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioFile] error:NULL];
    //[av prepareToPlay];
    isPairActive = FALSE;


    appDelegate = (ZogajAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    int position;

    for(int i = 0; i < ((appDelegate.numberOfPairs*2)/5); i++){

        for (int j = 0; j<5 ;j++){


            Button *button = [[Button alloc] init];

            //Sätter bild nummer..
            position = (arc4random() % [appDelegate.cardsInPlay count]);
            button.picNumber = [[appDelegate.cardsInPlay objectAtIndex:position]intValue];
                        NSLog(@"%d", button.picNumber);
            [appDelegate.cardsInPlay removeObjectAtIndex:position];

            button.frame = CGRectMake( 3 + (65 * j), 5 + (65 * i), 55, 55);
            button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            button.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:button];
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j<((appDelegate.numberOfPairs*2) % 5) ;j++){


        Button *button = [[Button alloc] init];

        //Sätter bild nummer..
        position = (arc4random() % [appDelegate.cardsInPlay count]);
        button.picNumber = [[appDelegate.cardsInPlay objectAtIndex:position]intValue];
        NSLog(@"%d", button.picNumber);
        [appDelegate.cardsInPlay removeObjectAtIndex:position];

        button.frame = CGRectMake( 3 + (65 * j), 5 + (65 * ((appDelegate.numberOfPairs*2)/5) + 1), 55, 55);
        //button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        //button.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];

        [self.view addSubview:button];
    }
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    Button *button = [[Button alloc] init];
    button = sender;
    NSLog(@"%d och spela upp ljud", button.picNumber);
    NSString *newAudioFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"double_card" ofType:@"mp3"];
    [av initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioFile] error:NULL];
    [av play];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",button.picNumber]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];

    if(isPairActive == FALSE){
        isPairActive = TRUE;
        firstButton = button;
    }
    else {
        secondButton = button;
        [self secondCard];
    }

    return;
}

- (void)secondCard {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
    NSString *newAudioFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"double_card" ofType:@"mp3"];
    isPairActive = FALSE;
    if([appDelegate.dictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",secondButton.picNumber]] == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",firstButton.picNumber]){
        NSString *newAudioFile2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"right_sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
        [av initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioFile2] error:NULL];
        [av play];
    }
    else {
        [firstButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [secondButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [av initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioFile] error:NULL];
        [av play];
    }
    return;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [av release];
    [firstButton release];
    [secondButton release];
}


@end
```

Comment: I think you should use an NSTimer instead of messing with NSThread.

Answer (score 2):

In `buttonPressed:` change the background, set an NSTimer to call you back, and return. In the NSTimer callback, set the background back to what you want.

Drawing doesn't happen at the moment you ask for it. That would give you horrible performance. All drawing is merged into the draw portion of the run loop. You won't get to that portion until you return from this IBAction method.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, the image will be changed after returning from the method. That's it.

You have to return from the method, so you have to change the image, perform selector that executes the rest of code you want to perform and return from the method.

UIKit can run only on main thread, so you have to return from the method, that's blocking it, and it will execute GUI manipulations then.

EDIT:
Instead of telling NSThread to sleep, perform the selector with delay.